# What to study to solve this type of problems?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I solved the following problem by trial and error, and still have not proper understanding of how i did that.

There is a function cons : 
`const cons = (x, y) => f => f(x, y);`

Cons store value to a variable pair :
`const pair = cons(5, 3);`

Create two functions car and cdr which each of them gonna return a argument of each.

`car(pair); // 5`

`cdr(pair); // 3`

I looked up into function composition and currying but didn't find any similar as this one. What should i study to get a better understanding in this topic?

EDIT: 
(the solution)

`const car = pair => pair((x, y) => x);`

`const cdr = pair =>pair((x,y) => y);`

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Learn about javascript arrow function

Comment: Check this one https://github.com/mbeaudru/modern-js-cheatsheet

Comment: The biggest part of this problem is probably just to properly analyze the question and what it means. Dealing with formal languages would make this a lot easier due to the practice with abstract concepts, so I'd say "do some formal basics of computer science". It doesn't apply directly on terms of knowledge, it's more about the ability to tackle the problem.

Comment: @31piy I think the OP did a fair job of explaing the problem but chose an bad title - if any reason to close it would be a duplicate of a question explaing arrow functions. Refering the OP to such a duplicate would be the help needed.

Comment: "I solved the problem by trial and error" - show the solution - seriously, if you show your solution, someone may be able to help you understand how you got to your solution, which is really what you are asking

Comment: @JaromandaX update with the solution

Comment: @brk i understand completely how arrow functions work, even if i wrote the exact same problem without using the arrows i would still not able to understand the solution

Answer (score 2):

You could take two more function who return a special argument, like `left` and `right` and the two wanted function for `car` and `cdr` which returns the call of the closure.

A standard way is to look, what you have

```
cons = (x, y) => f => f(x, y)
```

and what you like to get

```
car(pair) // --> x
cdr(pair) // --> y
```

Then you need two function to get either `x` or y, which takes the closure `cons` over `x` and `y`.

The final decision is to use the function `car` and `cdr` to take a closure, which returns a function which takes a function `f` for calling.

The result is either the value of `x` or `y`.

```js
const
    cons = (x, y) => f => f(x, y),
    left = (l, r) => l,
    right = (l, r) => r,
    car = fn => fn(left),
    cdr = fn => fn(right),
    pair = cons(5, 3);

console.log(car(pair)); // 5
console.log(cdr(pair)); // 3
```

Comment: this is a *solution* - but the OP has (apparently, according to him) a solution, just wants to know how to get to a solution without "trial and error" I guess

Comment: @JaromandaX exactly!